# Which tank would be the first to get emptied given the following conditions?

Tags: probability

There are 5 milk tanks in a dairy farm-A,B,C,D,E.Each contains 3300 l of Milk .Milk is pumped from one tank to the other as follows.

From A to C @ 130l/m

From B to E @ 100l/m

From B to A @ 80l/m

From E to C @ 210l/m

From D to B @ 30l/m

From C to D @ 250l/m

> $1$ Which tank would be the first to get emptied?
>
> $2$ How long will it take to get emptied?

options

a) D,$12$minutes b) B,$22$minutes c) A,$66$minutes d) E,$30$minutes

My Approach:

I did

For A=$3300$-$130$+$80$=$3250$

For B=$3300$-$180$+$30$=$3150$

For C=$3300$-$250$+$210$+$130$=$3390$

For D=$3300$-$30$+$250$=$3520$

For E=$3300$-$210$+$100$=$3190$

From here, I get B would take minimum time to get empty.

It will take

$1$ /$3150$

> Is my approach right? Why I am wrong can anyone give me the hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close. Since B loses 150 liters per minute, it will lose all 3,300 liters in 22 minutes.

Nonetheless, is this a trick question?
First you state that the containers are filled with water. Later you state that they are filled with milk. Which is it?

Comment: I edited the post It was a type mistake.Thanku so much I understood my mistake too